# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que los usuarios se registren para ver mi blog basado en wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Conocen algún plugin que me permita poner en privado mi blog, de modo que la gente que quiera acceder deba registrarse, y que después accedan al contenido pero sólamente del blog no del sitio web, es decir que sea el blog únicamente lo que esté en privado.

Comment: Te pondria un enlace a un tutorial que explica como hacerlo y es de Gonzalo Navarro.Pero por aqui no dejan poner enlaces y escribirlo me puede llevar mas de media hora, capturas etc. Te recomiendo que busques "Restringir Contenido en Wordpress" Hay varias formas de hacerlo.
Suerte

Comment: @Dr.Manhattan se permiten enlaces, siempre y cuando expliques lo esencial.

Answer (score 2):

Una tecnica que empleo muchas veces es crear un subdominio para el blog, por ejemplo: blog.midominioprincipal.com.

En el subdominio puedes instalar otro sitio web usando Wordpress y usando alguno de los muchos Wordpress plugins que existen (de pago y gratuitos) para controlar el acceso.

Estos son algunos de los plugins que puedes usar:

- Memberpress
- Restrict Content Pro
- aMember Pro

Puedes hacer una busqueda por plugins de membresia si deseas ver los resultados tu mismo.

Answer (score 0):

yo uso el plugin [User Access Shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-access-shortcodes/), si bien no te oculta la url de las páginas del sitemap, si te permite elegir que mostrar a ciertos usuarios:

- como aquellos que no hayan iniciado sesión

  ```
  [UAS_guest hint="" in="" admin="1"]
  Visible solamente para visitantes.
  [/UAS_guest]
  ```
- aquellos que iniciaron sesión

  ```
  [UAS_loggedin hint="" ex=""]
  Visible solo apra usuarios registrados.
  [/UAS_loggedin]
  ```
- aquellos que especifiques mediante su id en la base de datos

  ```
  [UAS_specific hint="" ids="" admin="1"]
  This content can only be seen by some selected users.
  [/UAS_specific]
  ```